# (Android) How can I start a service upon file selection?

Tags: android, service

I need to discover the method for starting an iconified background service upon selection of a specific file type. I have been at this all day and it is driving me up the wall :(

The following is what I have arrived at thus far:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    <data android:pathPattern="*.txt" />
</intent-filter>
```

---

```
public class MainThread extends Service {
    public MainThread() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "The new Service was Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // This is where I process my file...
        Toast.makeText(this, " Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: How are you selecting the file. Is this selection occur from some listview or what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern="*.txt" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainThread.class));
        finish();
        return;
}
```